# Настройки консоли

Tags: visual-studio

Установил VisualStudio 2017. Во время отладки консольного приложения в выводе неудобочитаемый шрифт. Не могу дефолтные найти настройки шрифта и цвета для консольного приложения.

При попытке изменения настроек в самом окне для оной отладки эти настройки не сохраняются.

Где найти общие настройки консоли для вновь создаваемых консольных приложений?

Comment: Какая консоль и какой язык? И при чём тут отладка?

Comment: @Qwertiy, Язык C#. 
Нужно чтобы при создании нового проекта во время отладки консоль была с нужными мне настройками, а не с дефолтными, которые лежат непонятно где.

Comment: ссылка на решение проблемы...
http://www.cyberforum.ru/cpp-beginners/thread937130.html